# How do you figure out what relations of $A \times A$ are not transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have found all 16 relations on a two element set. But now I can not find the ones which are not transitive. I dont know how ($xRy \land yRz) \implies xRz$ relates to this conversation.

This should be obvious because some relations in this context have $x,y,z,w$ elements.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how $(xRy∧yRz)⟹xRz$ relates to this conversation.

It is $\forall x\,\forall y\,\forall z\;\Big(\big(x\mathop Ry\wedge y\mathop Rz\big) \to x\mathop Rz\Big)$.

Transitivity is the claim that *if* there is some indirect relationship from one entity ($x$) to another entity ($z$), through some bridge ($y$), *then* there *must* be a direct relationship.

It's not a matter of finding cases that satisfy this condition, just that *no* case can be found to *falsify* it.

Another way to express transitivity is that:
$$\neg\,\exists x\,\exists y\,\exists z\;\Big(\big(x\mathop Ry\wedge y\mathop Rz\big)\wedge\neg x\mathop Rz\Big)$$

So if you can find *any* such indirect relationship but *cannot* find a corresponding direct relationship, then the entire relation is not transitive.

Only if you can demonstrate that *no* such counterexample exists can you claim transitivity.

Comment: okay you have made things extremely clear. I cannot commend you enough. what about the relation $(y,x)$ here i have $(y,?) \land (?,x) \implies (y,x)$ [where the question mark indicates either x or y] but if $(y,x) \land (x,x) \implies (y,x)$ we dont have a $(x,x)$ in the relation so that means this would false too? @GrahamKemp

Comment: @BigMike Implications are true when their antecedents are false.  They are only false when antecedent is true *and* the consequent is false.  Only having a bridge and no direct path forms a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

The relation $\{(a_1,a_2), (a_2,a_1)\}$ is not transitive. We can prove this by contradiction: assume the relation is transitive. We have that $a_1\sim a_2$, and that $a_2\sim a_1$. This means that by transitivity, we must have that $a_1\sim a_1$. But we don't. This is a contradiction, so the above relation is not transitive.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30987/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-s-how-do-you-figure-out-what-relations-of-a-times).

Comment: @GrahamKemp then what about the relation $(x,y), (y,x)$ here we have $(x,y) \land (y,x) \implies (x,x)$ this is false. but everywhere I go it says that $(x,x)$ must exist in the relation.

Comment: @Big Mike. Definition : A binary relation on a set $S$ is any subset of $S\times S$. Example "<" on  $N$,the  set of positive integers, is $L=\{(m,n)\in N\times N :\exists r\in N (m+r=n)\} .$  A set theorist will write $<=L$ which looks strange but in this context, "$<$" is a set.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $R$ is not transitive.Equivalently, for some $a,b,c$ we have $(a,b)\in R \wedge (b,c)\in R\wedge (a,c)\not \in R.$ If you put $a=b$ or $b=c$ into this you get a contradiction. So $a \ne b\wedge b\ne c$. Since $a,b,c$ belong to $\{x,y\}$ with $x\ne y$ this gives, equivalently,  (i) $(x,y)\in R\wedge (y,x)\in R\wedge (x,x)\not \in R$ or (ii) $(y,x)\in R\wedge (x,y)\in R\wedge (y,y)\not \in R$. That is, $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ both belong to $R$ and at least one of $(x,x),(y,y)$ does not. In all, $3$ non-transitive binary relations on $\{x,y\} $ : $R_1=A , R_2=A\cup \{(x,x)\}, R_3=A\cup \{(y,y)\}$ where $A=\{(x,y),(y,x)\}.$